# Python attr.s multiple type validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-attrs

A class that generates a UUID by default if none is provided, and validates/creates a UUID object if a `str` is provided.

```
import attr
from attrs import validators
from uuid import UUID, uuid1

def _validate(instance, attribute, value) -> None:
    try:
        if isinstance(value, str):
            instance.uuid = UUID(value)
        return
    except Exception as e:
        raise BadUUID() from e


@attr.s(slots=True)
class Private:
    uuid = attr.ib(type=[str, UUID], validator=[validators.optional([validators.instance_of(UUID), validators.instance_of(str)]), _validate], default=uuid1())
```

It should with and without providing a value:

```
print(Private())
print(Private('d283a713-9f4b-1c15-ab8d-8d95d7ce8999'))
```

In the case there is none provided it should generate a new UUID using the default setting.

If value is provided it should validated it and create a UUID object.

---

I get an error because it will only validate one instance type, either `str` or `UUID`.

If I set `instance_of(UUID)` it will only work without providing a value.

And if I set it to `instance_of(str)` it will only work with a `str` being provided.

---

Am I doing something wrong, is there a better way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: Why is `_validate` passed `attribute`? What should happen if `value` is not a string, currently it just returns with no change?

Comment: @Grismar I'm not using `attribute`, it was like that in the documentation. `Private` should only be initiated with an `str` or empty. If it is initiated with `str` then it should go through `_validate`. If `Private` is initiated empty it should resort to `default=uuid1()` which returns a `UUID` object. I am not sure if `instance.uuid = UUID(value)` is the correct way of setting this.

Comment: @Grismar This is what I came up with, is it correct? `def _validate(inst, attr, value) -> None:
    print('---- validate')
    if isinstance(value, str):
        try:
            object.__setattr__(inst, 'uuid', UUID(value))
        except Exception as e:
            raise BadUUID() from e


@attr.s(slots=True, frozen=True)
class Private:
    uuid = attr.ib(
        type=(str, UUID),
        validator=validators.optional([validators.instance_of((str, UUID)), _validate]),
        default=uuid1()
    )
`

Comment: Don't post code in comments, add to your question if you think you're closer to the answer, but answers provided are not yet correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is what you're after:

```
import attr
from uuid import UUID, uuid1


def _convert(value) -> UUID:
    return value if isinstance(value, UUID) else UUID(value)


@attr.s(slots=True)
class Private:
    uuid = attr.ib(default=uuid1(), converter=_convert)


p1 = Private()
print(p1.uuid)

p2 = Private('c53358b3-798e-11ec-a49b-cf6d4243e811')
print(p2.uuid)
```

Example result:

```
d5e2d087-798e-11ec-9d59-cf6d4243e811
c53358b3-798e-11ec-a49b-cf6d4243e811
```

If you prefer that *only* strings are converted and your own exception is raised if anything else was passed (although I'd probably just leave it up to `UUID()` itself), this works:

```
import attr
from uuid import UUID, uuid1


class BadUUID(Exception):
    ...


def _convert(value) -> UUID:
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return UUID(value)
    elif isinstance(value, UUID):
        return value
    else:
        raise BadUUID(f'{value} is neither a string nor a UUID')


@attr.s(slots=True)
class Private:
    uuid = attr.ib(default=uuid1(), converter=_convert)


p = Private(42)
```

Or if your intent was to catch exceptions from UUID and add something:

```
import attr
from uuid import UUID, uuid1


class BadUUID(Exception):
    ...


def _convert(value) -> UUID:
    try:
        return value if isinstance(value, UUID) else UUID(value)
    except Exception as e:
        raise BadUUID (f'{value} is not a good UUID') from e


@attr.s(slots=True)
class Private:
    uuid = attr.ib(default=uuid1(), converter=_convert)


p = Private(42)
```

Comment: I like the first and third options with the `_convert`, however I am still going to add `validator=validators.optional([validators.instance_of((str, UUID))]),` because for some reason `UUID` will allow `int` of any length.

Comment: It's your solution, so it's your decision - I would only offer that it tends to be best not to surprise users of your code, so if UUID accepts some values, unless you have really good reasons not to want to accept them, you're best off not messing with them - people will expect your code to accept the same.